# Why was Malcolm Turnbull (Prime Minister of Australia) named in the Panama Papers?

Tags: australia, panama-papers

It has been reported that Malcolm Turnbull was in the Panama Papers.  What records did he have and what was he using their services for.

http://www.afr.com/news/politics/malcolm-turnbull-named-in-panama-papers-20160511-gosvit

Answer (score 5):

He was listed as a former director of a company (Star Technology Systems Limited) back in the 1990's, before retiring from the position in 1995.

The company itself was subsidiary of a company listed on the ASX.

An ABC article (http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-05-12/turnbull-listed-in-panama-papers/7407424) gives a bit more insight.

Basically, he wasn't 'using' anyone's services, but the legitimate company he was on the board of was incorporated by Mossack Fonseca. It should also be clearly noted that there has, at no time, been any suggestion of wrongdoing on his behalf (in this, at least).